# User Interface halts while using some methods of assembly reference dll

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using an assembly reference dll in c# that controls some network devices! when I try to connect network device, the user interface halts till connection establish!
To solving this problem I did use threads/ async-await (.Net Framework 4.0) but the problem is still not solved...

here is my code (using thread):

```
    public void startListening(string IP, string Port)
    {
        if (!ThreadBusy)
        {
            if (IP.Trim() == "" || Port.Trim() == "") return;
            Conn = new Thread(() => start(IP, Port));
            Conn.Start();
            ThreadBusy = true;
        }
    }

    private void start(string IP, string Port)
    {
        if (!bIsConnected && !isListening)
        {
            //This Line Will Make UI Freez...
            bIsConnected =  axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                iMachineNumber = 1;
                deviceType = axCZKEM1.IsTFTMachine(iMachineNumber) ? 1 : 2;
                this.IP = IP;
                this.isListening = true;
                if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535))
                {
                    switch (deviceType)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            EnableTFTEvents();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            EnableBWEvents();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //---
                            break;
                    }
                    ConnectionFailedArgs args = new ConnectionFailedArgs();
                    args.IP = IP;
                    OnConnectionSucceed(args);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectionFailedArgs args = new ConnectionFailedArgs();
                args.IP = IP;
                OnConnectionFailed(args);
            }
            ThreadBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

I want to know what happening on UI while using this thread?

I Upgrade my VS from 2010 to 2012 (.Net Framework 4.5) but The problem is still not solved!

Here is my code (using async-await) :

```
        public async void startListening(string IP, string Port)
    {
        if (!ThreadBusy)
        {
            if (IP.Trim() == "" || Port.Trim() == "") return;

            //Conn = new Thread(() => start(IP, Port));
            //Conn.Start();
            ThreadBusy = true;
            await Task.Run(() => start(IP,Port));
        }
    }

    private async Task start(string IP, string Port)
    {
        if (!bIsConnected && !isListening)
        {
            //This Line Will Make UI Freez...
            bIsConnected =  axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
            if (bIsConnected == true)
            {
                deviceType = axCZKEM1.IsTFTMachine(iMachineNumber) ? 1 : 2;
                this.IP = IP;
                this.isListening = true;
                if (axCZKEM1.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535)) 
                    switch (deviceType)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            EnableTFTEvents();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            EnableBWEvents();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            //---
                            break;
                    }
                    ConnectionFailedArgs args = new ConnectionFailedArgs();
                    args.IP = IP;
                    OnConnectionSucceed(args);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ConnectionFailedArgs args = new ConnectionFailedArgs();
                args.IP = IP;
                OnConnectionFailed(args);
            }
            ThreadBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Aync/await` is not same as `Threads` and it was introduced in .Net 4.5

Comment: I know! But I did download ["Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/5/7B59A157-A908-4F6E-85D7-EB93E3A4DC00/Async-CTP-v3.exe) package separately...

Comment: If you want to know what's happening on the UI thread then you'll need to use the debugger.  Use Debug + Windows + Threads to select it.  If you see it stuck in a loop, waiting for ThreadBusy then you'll certainly have found the problem.

Comment: What is Connect_Net? Is there an asynchronous version of it?

Comment: Connect_Net is a method that presented by an assembly reference dll. I can't access to Connect_Net code . . . By the way it must not be asynchronous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that the problem is when you create the thread. tell me, maybe you're doing `Join()` which might cause that or you're in a busy wait waiting for the thread to end.

make sure that in the thread you're creating you're not doing anything more then

```
     Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyFunc));
     t.Start();
```

and after creating the thread you're no doing something like

```
while(t.IsAlive == false)
   Sleep(20);
```

if you want to know when the thread ended you can invoke a method like so:

```
Invoke(new ThreadEnded(DoSomething));
```

Comment: @YounesJafari can you please share your code? i mean the code that creates a new thread

Comment: @YounesJafari judging from the code i can't see what's wrong. however i can give you some breadcrumbs for finding the problem.
first checks if the problem occur even if the thread doesn't start. if so then you have to share more of your code. if not, then take out each time some of the code in the thread to find out what the root of it

Comment: If you want more information let me say : The application have a winForm UI and a connection class. The startListening("192.168.0.77", "4370"); method of connection class will call by button_clicked event. Just it! The axCZKEM1 is an object of dll main class and dll source code is not available for me. by calling Connect_Net method (inside thread or task) the UI halts.

Comment: when the ui halts, press the pause button (make sure your'e on debug) in VS and look at the call stack of the UI (make sure you are looking at the right thread by opening the thread debug and selecting the main thread). there you will see where is the UI stuck. let me know what you find. btw, if you'll be so kind to accept my question, that'll be great :).

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misconception that `async/await` somehow make code create threads or execute asynchronously by themsleves. They do not. They actually instruct the compiler to execute any asynchronous method on which you call `await` on another thread and return execution on the original thread when the asynchronous method finishes. It is the asynchronous method that actually creates and schedules Tasks and (indirectly) makes use of threads.

You have to call `await` on an asynchronous operation, otherwise your entire method will execute in the original (ie the UI) thread.

This means that when you call Connect_Net you are still on the UI thread and your application will appear frozen.

You should check Stephen Toub's article "[Invoke the method with `await` ... ugh!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/03/13/quot-invoke-the-method-with-await-quot-ugh.aspx)" for a more detailed explanation.

The best solution is to use an asynchronous version of Connect_Net, if there is one available, and `await` on it eg.

```
private async Task start(string IP, string Port)
{
    if (!bIsConnected && !isListening)
    {
        //This Line Will Make UI Freez...
        bIsConnected =  await axCZKEM1.Connect_NetAsync(IP, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
...
```

If there is no such method, you can call Connect_Net asynchronously using [Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx)

```
private async Task start(string IP, string Port)
{
    if (!bIsConnected && !isListening)
    {
        //This Line Will Make UI Freez...
        bIsConnected =  await Task.Run(()=>axCZKEM1.Connect_Net(IP, Convert.ToInt32(Port)));

...
```

After `await` execution continues on the original SynchronizationContext (roughly the original thread for desktop applications). That means the UI can still freeze if the rest of the code takes a long time to run.

Comment: Connect_NetAsync is not available, also Connect_Net will return boolean value... how can I access to this? is it stored in Task.Result?

Comment: Yes, although await will unwrap it and return the bool value

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion code but the problem is still not solved! (The UI halts!)